# VHDL Fixed_pkg Getting bound check failure when adding 2 ufixed values

Tags: vhdl, fpga, fixed-point, ghdl

I am attempting to used the ufixed datatype and add 2 ufixed values together, I have calculated I should have enough bits to store the result and the output should be able to be stored in the signal, but when I attempt to perform it I get a bound check failure. Can someone tell me why I am getting this?

The important parts of the code are:

```
-- definition of parameters used in the failing calculation

input : in ufixed(0 downto -15); -- Q1.15

constant VectorLength : integer := 3;
type vector_ufixed is array(0 to VectorLength-1) of ufixed(1 downto -14);

constant InnerProductArray : vector_ufixed := (to_ufixed(1.2,1,-14), to_ufixed(1.0,1,-14), to_ufixed(0.2,1,-14));

signal InnerProductResult : ufixed(4 downto -29); -- Q5.29

signal counter : integer := 0;


write(l, real'image(to_real(InnerProductResult)));
write(l, string'(", "));
write(l, real'image(to_real(InnerProductResult + input*InnerProductArray(counter))));
writeline(output, l);
InnerProductResult <= InnerProductResult +                                                                            
                      input*InnerProductArray(counter);
```

When I simulate this with ghdl I get the following result:

```
0.0, 6.00006103515625e-1
ghdl:error: bound check failure at InnerProduct.vhd:55
  from: process work.innerproduct(innerproductarchitecture).P0 at InnerProduct.vhd:55
ghdl:error: simulation failed
```

line 55 in this case is the line 
`InnerProductResult <= InnerProductResult + input*InnerProductArray(counter);`

input takes the value 0.5, as can be observed from the resulting value of 6.00006103515625e-1 when input is multiplied by 1.2.

The value 6.00006103515625e^-1*2^29 is 322125824 as well which is an integer less than 2^34 so it should fit fine, I don't understand why this might be?

Comment: 6.00006103515625e^-1*2^29 is 322125824 as well which is an integer less than 2^34 so it should fit fine, I don't understand why this might be?

Comment: The problem appears to be that I need to resize the resulting addition result by performing 

    `InnerProductResult <= InnerProductResult + resize(input, 34)*resize(InnerProductArray(counter), 34);`

So that the result of the addition is 34 bits wide. This works if these variables are unsigned, but not if they are ufixed. I get `no overloaded function found matching ''resize''`

Comment: You don't provide a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), not identifying line 55, not providing a value for `input` nor allowing the reader to replicate your error message. (Note that textio is not portable - IEEE Std 1076-2008 Annex D, there's no guarantee the output will appear as you show, it's dependent on fflush of standard output which isn't guaranteed). For those not quite curious enough to laboriously create an MCVe, Line 55 is the assignment to `InnerProductResult`. Your code snippet also has lots of trailing spaces.

Comment: I declined from including the entire code as it would pollute the question with a large amount of mostly irrelevant code that would confuse the part causing the issue. I included the relevant information in order to make it obvious what part of the code was causing the problem.

Comment: Didn't ask for your entire code, asked for an MCVe. Your question is unclear and the problem not reproducible as shown. That you learned something from the journey is fine. What about other Stackoverflow readers?

Comment: The input comes from running a testbench so to reproduce the problem you would need the entire working code for the file and testbench.

Comment: I was trying to keep it as minimal as possible so future readers could get a clear idea of the issue without wading through many lines of code as this tends to put people off and lead people to look for other, more minimal, clear questions.

Comment: [The code for an MCVe doesn't have to be large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9KmES.jpg) and the problem would stand out, particularly identifying the line with the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When performing a arithmetic operations such as this, addition and multiplication in this case, it is necessary to resize the result of the operation to fit into the location it is being stored. In this case we add a 34 bit number to 2 16 bit numbers and so we need to resize the result to be 34 bits wide in order to fit precisely into the storage location i.e. InnerProductResult.

The syntax for resize in fixed_pkg appears to differ from that used in numeric_std for signed and unsigned numbers. The following syntax is nessesary to use for operations done with fixed_pkg, this was found in http://www.klabs.org/mapld05/presento/189_lewis_p.pdf:

```
InnerProductResult <= resize(                                                                                         
    arg => InnerProductResult + input*InnerProductArray(counter),                                                       
    size_res => InnerProductResult                                                                                      
    );
```

Comment: Because resize it is necessary to resize the result of adding and multiplication values as they are being put into a value of a different size than that of themselves, I'll update my answer to make that more clear.

Comment: In another, very similar piece of code I have a similar line where I have           

`InnerProductResult <= InnerProductResult + input*InnerProductArray(counter);`

Where the InnerProductResult is a 34 bit unsigned, input and InnerProductArray(counter) are 16 bit unsigneds. The values are the same an in this case apart from the values stored are integers multiplied by the appropriate power of 2. Why is it that in this case resize is not necessary?

Comment: Did you just ask a question on StackOverflow to write your own answer?

Comment: No, I asked the question and then found out the answer before anyone else answered it when experimenting with different solutions and reading the linked pdf